# News list multi-columns layout using Grids or Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout

**INTRO**

I'd need to implement a layout such the following one to list "*Last News*" items.

[image]

I recieve a list of equal items (for example `.card DIVs` ) and eventually I could limit the total to a specific number, for example "the most 7 recent items".

Obviously, I'd like that the most recent News is placed in "1" position, and the previous one that was there, will be moved to "2" position and so on...

**IMPLEMENTATION**

*At [this link](https://codepen.io/ldetomi/pen/abadXRE) I tried to implement two different layout, the first one using Flex and the second one using Grid.*

**Flex Solution:**

It seems almost perfect and flexible because, for example is possible also to insert another item besides "2" and "3" elements or after "7" one, and layout is automatically adaped.

The unique CONs is that I'd need to separate `.card` items into two distinct columns in html

```
<div class="wrapper-multi-column">
  <div class="main-column">
    <div class="card">1</div>
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-column">
    <div class="card">4</div>
    <div class="card">5</div>
    <div class="card">6</div>
    <div class="card">7</div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper-multi-column {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  
  .card {
    background: lightgray;
  }
  
  .main-column {
    flex: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
    
    .card {
      flex: 1;
      
      &:first-of-type {
        flex-basis: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
  
  .side-column {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px;
  }
}
```

**Grid Solution:**

In this case is possible to have a simple list of `.card` items in a single wrapper, but adding new elements force me to edit also sCSS code, to set specific rule also for new items, that is quite unconfortable.

```
<div class="wrapper-single">
   <div class="card">1</div>
   <div class="card">2</div>
   <div class="card">3</div>
   <div class="card">4</div>
   <div class="card">5</div>
   <div class="card">6</div>
   <div class="card">7</div>
</div>

.wrapper-single {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    'one one four'
    'one one five'
    'two three six'
    'two three seven';
  margin: 80px 0;
  
  .card {
    background: darkgray;
    
    &:nth-child(1) {
      grid-area: one;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      grid-area: two;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      grid-area: three;
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
      grid-area: four;
    }
    &:nth-child(5) {
      grid-area: five;
    }
    &:nth-child(6) {
      grid-area: six;
    }
    &:nth-child(7) {
      grid-area: seven;
    }
  }
}
```

I think that Grid Layout could be the best layout technique, in general, for this kind of layout, but I'm less involved in this technique and I know it only a little.

**Please, do you have suggestions/ideas to combine advantages** of HTML of second implementation and "robustness" of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid with for each first level element inside a grid-area with row start, col start, row end, col end.

That works with the 7 items limitation.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper-single {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  background: darkgray;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 2;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 5 / 3;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(7) {
  grid-area: 4 / 3 / 5 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-single">
  <div class="card">div1</div>
  <div class="card">div2</div>
  <div class="card">div3</div>
  <div class="card">div4</div>
  <div class="card">div5</div>
  <div class="card">div6</div>
  <div class="card">div7</div>
</div>
```

Now if you want to have more than 7 elements, the column on right could be scrolling and you add elements in this column. In this case, first grid is simpler and the right cell have a nested grid inside.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper-single {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  background: darkgray;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: white;
}

.wrapper-single>div.card:nth-child(4)>div {
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-single">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card">4</div>
    <div class="card">5</div>
    <div class="card">6</div>
    <div class="card">7</div>
    <div class="card">8</div>
    <div class="card">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now for the problem of inserting in between, it also possible with 5 cols and card 1 covers 4 cols, cols 2 and 3 cover 2 cols.... and so on... Now everything has limit, grid is grid you still have to define a certain number of cols and a certain number of cols...

Comment: Thank you pier but... your first example is it not the same approach that I used in my second example, the Grid-layout one? with the same limitations adding new items?

Comment: it always have limitation in adding, reason I put the second example. Grid is 2 dimensions layout, flex is one dimension. Either can work in different situation, but as soon you structure your layout, you can't explode the structure everywhere. You have to determine that this will be "fix", this part can increase...

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the power of implicit grid creation and do something like below. You can add/remove items and the grid will get adjust automatically. I have a detailed article about such technique for more detail and examples: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-css-grids-implicit-grid-and-auto-placement-powers/

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; /* equal columns*/
  grid-auto-rows: 80px; /* the size of one row */
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.container > :first-child {
  grid-area: span 2/span 2; /* 2 rows / 2 columns */
}
.container > :nth-child(2),
.container > :nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: span 2; /* 2 rows */
  grid-column: 1; /* place at first column */
}
.container > :nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 2; /* place at 2nd column */
}
.container > :nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 3; /* create a third column*/
}
/* if only two elements span all columns */
.container > :nth-child(2):last-child {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

/* */
.container {counter-reset:num;margin:10px;border:2px solid red;}
.container > div {background: #f3f3f3;font-size:20px;}
.container > div:before {content:counter(num);counter-increment:num}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Temani but... If in your first example, I add a new DIV, it will wrap on another row and not placed after the last one as in my first example (the one done using flex-layout). Usually is not what is desired (start a new row), I'd like to simply divide space in a different way (the flex solution seems the most flexible and adaptable solution but it needs two html container...)